# Opencv - Release memory changing cv::Mat refcount to zero

Tags: c++, opencv

Can I release memory using this approach?

```
    while(true){
        Mat img = imread("C:/image.jpg");
        img.refcount = 0;
        img.release();
    }
```

What can happen if the memory is deallocated in this way? Assuming that the point indicated is safe.

Comment: maybe you meant "*(img.refcount) = 0;" (refcount is itself a pointer)

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: you would *never* want to manually adjust refcounts ;)

Comment: @B... : Thank you for your interest. In summary I start processing from a cv :: Mat instance, pitch it to a class and add this image to a vector object. There is a moment in which I need to remove some imagens for memory (images that are no longer used). I do this with vecto.erase() (passing the parameters correctly). The problem is that the images are not removed (I presume) because after some interactions the machine stay very slow (memory leak??).

Comment: @berak : How I explain to @ B..., I have memory leak! I try to solve it using this strategy.

Comment: @rwvaldivia, you either *trust* the internal refcounting (then do nothing), or you don't. (then don't touch it). also, show your *real* code, not the dummy above

Comment: @rwvaldivia if this is the sort of thing you do in your code then it is perhaps not surprising that you have memory leaks. Could you post some code  that demonstrates the leak, preferably in a runnable example? BTW, how do you know the images are not removed by vector::erase()?

Answer (score 2):

If you try to deallocate memory like that you won't succeed. Looking at the source code (see below), if recount is NULL deallocation is not performed. In fact refcount  is set to NULL when a Mat is constructed with a pointer to user allocated data.

```
inline void Mat::release()
{
    if( refcount && CV_XADD(refcount, -1) == 1 )
        deallocate();
    data = datastart = dataend = datalimit = 0;
    size.p[0] = 0;
    refcount = 0;
}
```

If on the other hand, as suggested by MariusSiuram, you set what refcount points at to zero, the deallocation will succeed. 
But I am not sure why you would want to do that because the destructor for `img` will take care of the deallocation for you.

Regarding your comments about erasing Mats in a vector, here is a demonstration:

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lena.jpg"); 
    cout << "*refcount = " << (*img.refcount) << " should be 1" << endl;
    vector<cv::Mat> v;
    v.push_back(img);
    v.push_back(img);
    v.push_back(img);
    v.push_back(img);
    cout << "*refcount = " << (*img.refcount) << " should be 5" << endl;
    auto f = v.begin();
    ++f;
    v.erase(f);
    cout << "*refcount = " << (*img.refcount) << " should be 4" << endl;
    f = v.end();
    --f;
    v.erase(f);
    cout << "*refcount = " << (*img.refcount) << " should be 3" << endl;
    v.resize(0);
    cout << "*refcount = " << (*img.refcount) << " should be 1" << endl;
    img.release();
    cout << "refcount ptr = " << (img.refcount) << " should be 0" << endl; 
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
*refcount = 1 should be 1
*refcount = 5 should be 5
*refcount = 4 should be 4
*refcount = 3 should be 3
*refcount = 1 should be 1
refcount ptr = 00000000 should be 0
```

Comment: Tks B... After reading your reply I start understand how refcount works. Then I just make a debug in my code, checking where the refcount was changed and I find the location where memory leaks and make release in cv::Mat object. Now my code works fine. Thank you so much!